# Developing a web app with Mono (opensource .NET) any examples?

Tags: linux, web-applications, f#, mono, spring.net

I am a Java, Scala, Python web app Linux guy. I want to play around with Mono (particularly F#) for web development.

I am just looking for an example web application written in Mono perhaps in Github (any CLI language is fine).  I have tried googling and cannot find a good starting point (or if its even possible).

From what I gather I could sort of combine:

- Fast CGI (nginx, lighttpd)
- Mono
- Spring framework .NET (I can't even tell if it will work on Mono)

Advanced apologies if there is a glaringly obvious resource (web site) that I missed.

(useful site: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Resources/GetMono.aspx)

Comment: Not a Linux guy, but have you considered [WebSharper](http://websharper.com/home)? It seems to be the preferred choice for F# web development. Alternatively, you could put the logic in an F# lib and reference that from a C# ASP.NET/MVC project.

Comment: I did see that a while ago when it was younger. I need to check if it works on mono. F# is totally bad ass. I like it better than Scala.

Comment: afaik there are some issues with spring.net for mono; see the [bug tracker](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET/component/10946), with an issue "add mono support".

Answer (score 5):

To get F# dev environment for Mac/Linux setup:

- http://www.tryfsharp.org/Resources/GetMono.aspx

For Ubuntu 12.04 specifically:

- http://datachomp.com/archives/running-asp-net-mvc4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

To Get Fsharp to work with MonoDevelop 2.6 or greater you have to use one of forks of:

- https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding

Nancy looks like a good URL routing option which is all I really need:

- https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy

And for F# Mono stuff for Nancy including Djano templating:

- https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Building-Nancy-on-Mono

You can use the command line NuGet install tool (which is basically like Javascripts npm or Java's maven):

- http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939

Once I install the Fsharp Powerpack I should have in theory LINQ to use for persistence.

And If Nancy does not work out there appears to be a standard called OWIN (it appears to be analogous to Python's WSGI).

Other OWIN compliant projects: http://owin.org/#projects

**UPDATE**

Looks like [**ServiceStack**](http://www.servicestack.net/) has some good stuff also and seems to be gaining some traction. In terms of Mono you mainly want to look at [daemon doc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux).

Answer (score 3):

Check out XSP (about halfway down this page)

[Mono & ASP.NET](http://mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

And besides WebSharper which Daniel mentioned there's also [Bistro](http://bistroframework.org/index.php?title=FSharp).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That does help. I feel dumb for not finding that page on the Mono site.

Comment: I may have to just roll my own with XSP. Maybe I can get Spring.NET to had some persistence support.