# Installing latest mono on Centos 6

Tags: mono, installation, centos, centos6

I am new to Linux (literally new- used it a couple of times) and I tried to install mono via yum; but I have gotten an outdated version that don't support .NET 4

How can I install mono 2.10.8?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10385627/318174 . By the way your question is not really a programming question and you might want to ask it on a different stackexchange.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, this is what I came up with and it worked for me:

based on [this](http://jmainguy.com/index.php/installing-mono-3-0-1-on-centos-linux-6-3/) article:

```
$yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget

$cd /usr/local/src 

$wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.1.tar.bz2

$tar jxf mono-3.0.1.tar.bz2

$cd mono-3.0.1

$./configure --prefix=/opt/mono

$make && make install
```

Then I downloaded the `MonoDevelop` IDE and compiled my program using Mono framework.

Then in Centos I called my program:

`/opt/mono/bin/mono /root/MyFolder/MyProgramDir/myProgram.exe "$@"`

Comment: Perfect installation, compiling no errors, no manual fix ups script runs from first go, didn't even need to run the yum command.

Comment: Only problem is I used `/opt/mono` should of instead used `/usr/local`

Comment: No errors for me either.  However, the very last step ("make && make install") takes about 30 minutes to run!  So go grab a beer before you start.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Hello World Console Application on CentOS 6.5, compiled with the Mono "mcs" command and run with the Mono "mono" command.  The first section was taken directly from Andrew's answer.  +1 for Andrew!  I added some additional steps because I am using the command line, not a Linux GUI.

```
yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget

cd /usr/local/src 

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.1.tar.bz2

tar jxf mono-3.0.1.tar.bz2

cd mono-3.0.1

./configure --prefix=/opt/mono

make && make install
```

**Adding mono bin to "PATH" environment variable:**

```
[root@localhost bin]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[root@localhost bin]# export PATH=/opt/mono/bin:$PATH
[root@localhost bin]# echo $PATH
/opt/mono/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
[root@localhost bin]#
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Mars!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Compile and Run:**

[image]

> Elon Musk's retirement party is planned for December 16, 2025!

**Compile *.sln file:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under CentOS 5 it's probably best to compile Mono from source to get a recent version.

It just so happens I have already written a complete set of instructions for doing this here (If you'll pardon me linking to one of my own pages):

http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx

Edit:

The above link is dead, best instructions are now at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/compiling-from-git/

Comment: Cool, I've bumped into the author! Would you be so awesome as to add a sentence or two before each line to explain to idiots like me what each command is actually doing? Thanks in advance. Votes later ;)

Comment: This link is currently dead.

Comment: @katbyte I've supplied a new URI with monos official documentation for building Mono, it works fine on CentOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

Mono packaging has always been in need of Love in the Fedora/RedHat world, so go figure if you're using CentOS.

Mono's Download page lists OpenSUSE, Debian and Ubuntu: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

I would use one of those options instead if you want to do something serious, otherwise you're on your own.

(Novell used to offer pre-built packages from CentOS [here](http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx), but all links there seem broken now. Furthermore, these seemed to be the "enterprisey" version, and anyway if you're going CentOS instead of RH you're already avoiding that sub-world I'm guessing...)