# Visual Studio + Mono: 'Gtk' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mono

I've just installed [mono 3](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) for Windows, and now I've opened a project that uses "Gtk". I'm trying to compile it but it's telling me "Gtk" could not be found, which I'm fairly certain mono installed, but evidently didn't set up the paths for.

How do I tell VS2012 where all the mono stuff is?

---

I've downgraded to mono 2. No luck yet.

Comment: This blog post was helpful: http://iggyma.blogspot.ca/2008/06/gtk-with-visual-studio.html except that it's still saying "Mono.Attach" doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GTK# with .NET (ie: not Mono), you need to download "Gtk# for .NET" from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html rather than Mono for Windows.

Comment: I'm confused. You linked me to exact same page. I don't care if it compiles against .net or mono, I just want to compile it. I'm trying to compile [mono-tools](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools). I opened the included project file, but..it won't compile.

Comment: Yes, I linked you to the exact same page, but told you to download something different from what you downloaded the first time.

Comment: Oh now I see, 3.x doesn't have "Gtk# for .NET" so I didn't notice it.

Comment: Anyway, it didn't help any. VS still can't find Gtk.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether `C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\` present on your machine? If not, you need to install GTK# runtime as @jpobst pointed out.

The simplest way of getting every bits (and more) is to download Xamarin 2.0

http://xamarin.com/download

and install. After that, you can create a new GTK# 2.0 project in Xamarin Studio, and then open the same project in Visual Studio and compile. (Verified on my machine.)

The Xamarin installation makes sure that everything you need is there. I don't think the Mono 3.0 installer does the same.

You can then compare the project you are trying to open in Visual Studio now and the new GTK# project Xamarin Studio created and see if there are obvious problems preventing it from being compiled.

Comment: Xamarin gives pretty much the exact same errors. [This thing](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools) is impossible to compile on Windows :\

Comment: Well, mono itself and mono-tools are built using makefile. They are not supposed to be built in VS or Xamarin Studio (unless it is carefully maintained by some volunteers on Windows). Thus, you will have to switch to makefile, or try to create the project files from scratch.

Comment: They had .sln files in there; I thought I could get away with it. Guess not. Oh well, thanks for your help.

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't trust those sln and csproj files in the repository. They are either only for Mono scenarios or out of date. So far I am only confident that Gerdarme related ones are VS compatible. I met problems with others, such as xbuild ones, and I did not play with every.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `MonoDevelop` IDE and compile it using mono framework. Check this out: [Installing latest mono on Centos 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782096)

Comment: Nope. This question is about Visual Studio and Windows. VS2012 + Win8.

Answer (score 0):

[mono runtime window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCWH6.jpg)>Well, it works for me, but on  the my way.

> As we know, -pkg not works, so I do manually with –r  reference for path to libraries, in one batch file.
>
> For example , program  hello.cs with  gtk  >
>   hellogtk1run.bat
>
> mcs hellogtk1.cs -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\pango-sharp.dll"
>
> -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\atk-sharp.dll"
>
> -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\gdk-sharp.dll"
>
> -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\gtk-sharp.dll"
>
> -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\gtk-sharp-2.0\glib-sharp.dll"
>
> ,put link sign for new row for every dll in .bat file.