# How can I tell if Mono is installed properly on Linux?

Tags: linux, mono

I asked IT to install Mono on CentOS using the following commands:

```
$yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget
$cd /usr/local/src 
$wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.2.5.tar.bz2
$tar jxf mono-3.2.5.tar.bz2
$cd mono-3.2.5
$./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
$make && make install
```

However, when I run `mono myapp.exe` I get

```
-bash: mono: command not found
```

I know nothing about Linux - I feel like I'm in Japan. Assuming Linux has a path variable or something like it, maybe mono isn't in the path?

I can't even find an executable called `mono` in `/usr/local/src`, just a `mono` folder. Mind you I can't work out how to even search for a file so I might not be looking properly.

How can I tell whether its installed correctly? Maybe its just not available to the non-admin account I use?

I'm lost. Help!

Comment: Try this: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=mono-opt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782096/installing-lastest-mono-on-centos-6/35450075#35450075

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `mono` is properly installed, you should *not* get a message like `-bash: mono: command not found`.  If something is *installed* then it most typically is in the `$PATH`.

On my system the executable is located on `/usr/bin/mono` (as most things are) but things may be different on a RPM-based system.

Your `./configure`, however, got the prefix `/opt/mono`, so probably your executable also is located under that special path.  (And thus `mono` isn't *properly* installed.)  Why did you install it there?  Anyway.  If this is the fact, then you can execute it using sth like

```
/opt/mono/bin/mono foo.exe
```

to find the executable below your prefix path you could use

```
find /opt/mono -name mono
```

to see all directory entries which are named exactly `mono`.  One of those should be your executable.

Comment: Cool, getting somewhere! So from within `/opt/mono/bin` I can run `./mono` and see the usage help. And thanks for the `find` tip.

Answer (score 7):

If your programm is properly installed you will usually find it's executable using "which"

```
which programm
```

like:

```
which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: find will look for it whether it's in path or not

Answer (score 3):

There are many guides and tutorials out there that recommend installing in `/opt/mono` in order to not conflict with the mono supplied by official distribution packages (which would be installed in `/usr`).

However what most of those guides miss is that `/opt/mono` is a non-standard prefix that will not be taken in account by the system when trying to find the executables (the system looks at the $PATH environment variable).

There are 2 possible solutions to this:

- Instead of using the prefix `/opt/mono` use `/usr/local` (which is actually what `./configure` or `./autogen.sh` uses by default if you don't supply any prefix!). This prefix is normally included in the $PATH environment variable of most distributions.
- Use your custom mono installation from a [Parallel Environment](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments). This is a bit more complicated to set up, but it's specially recommended for people who want to install two versions of mono in parallel (i.e. a very modern version, and a more stable version supplied by the official distribution packages), and have good control of when they can use one or another.

The reason that many internet tutorials recommend `/opt/mono` instead of `/usr/local` is actually because most of them are based on the wiki page (referenced above) that explains how to set up a Mono Parallel Environment, but they of course don't include the other steps to properly set up such an environment (they just borrowed the bit about how to call configure).